# Paragraphs are overlapping in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

Live demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/4M5dq/

I am running Firefox 8 for mac and am getting strange behaviour from paragraphs on my website, it is acting as if the paragraphs are out of the document flow and stacking them on top of each other.

Safari + Chrome are working as expected.

Does anyone know what is causing this? Would be useful for others to confirm the issue is also present for them.

Comment: Present for me, on Firefox 8.0.1/Windows XP. Weird.

Comment: you might consider posting examples to static uri, like jsfiddle.net, as it will preserve the code for future viewers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you remove `display: -moz-inline-stack;` from  `#frontpage` element, paragraphs don't overlap anymore

Comment: Thank's, I need `-moz-inline-stack` for older versions of firefox but if I declare it before `inline-block` then current versions will use `inline-block` instead and this solved the issue.

Comment: so try -moz-inline-box instead for older FF

Comment: That causes everything to stop wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Can't test where I am... no FireFox.  But I wonder if it has to do with this

```
p.dropcap::first-letter {
    float: left;
```

Maybe FF is applying the `float` to the entire paragraph?